# How can I change my python code avoid computed the maxnumber index

Tags: python, numpy

Now I have implemented python code.

```
def logistic(z):
    return 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-z))
def gradient_testing(X,Y,w):
   K = len(w)
   N = len(X)
   s = np.zeros(K)

   for i in range(N):
         s += Y[i] * X[i] * logistic(-Y[i] * np.dot(X[i], w))

   s = -1 *s/N
   return s
```

`X` is 80*23 matrix, `w` is 1 *23 martix, `Y` is 80*1 matrix.From my code it will return 1*23 every time after every iterations.But it didn't satisfy my requirement.

In the first iterations, it will return 1*23 value,and then i will choose the biggest one,for example, it's the `s[8]`. And the current iteration, `s[8]` will not be updated from `Y[i] * X[i] * logistic(-Y[i] * np.dot(X[i], w))`. In this iteration, if the 8th element in `Y[i] * X[i] * logistic(-Y[i] * np.dot(X[i], w))` is the biggest, then in the next iteration `s[9]` will not be updated. How can I change my code?

Comment: IS X, and Y are of same length?

Comment: Not fully understand your question. If in the current iteration `s[8]` is the maximum value, in the next iteration, you want to get `s[0], s[1], s[2]...s[7], 0, s[9]...`, without s[8]?

Comment: yes,s[8] keep the value that computed last iteration

Answer (score 0):

Brief explanation, `k_range!=max_idx` makes a array having: `1` where index is not equal to the index of previous maximum and `0` where index is equal to the index of previous maximum. During the first iteration, `max_idx` is -1, so `k_range!=max_idx` gives a array of 1's.

```
def gradient_testing(X,Y,w):
    K = len(w)
    N = len(X)
    s = np.zeros(K)
    max_idx=-1
    k_range=np.arange(K)

    for i in range(N):
        _temp_max= Y[i] * X[i] * logistic(-Y[i] * np.dot(X[i], w))
        s+=_temp_max*(k_range!=max_idx)
        max_idx=np.argmax(_temp_max)

    s = -1 *s/N
    return s
```